# CUDA kernel launched from Nsight Compute gives inconsistent results

Tags: cuda, nsight

I have completed writing my CUDA kernel, and confirmed it runs as expected when I compile it using nvcc directly, by:

1. Validating with test data over 100 runs (just in case)
2. Using cuda-memcheck (memcheck, synccheck, racecheck, initcheck)

Yet, the results printed into the terminal while the application is getting profiled using Nsight Compute differs from run to run. I am curious if the difference is a cause for concern, or if this is the expected behavior.

Note: The application also gives correct & consistent results while getting profiled bu nvprof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue by addressing my shared memory **initializations**. Since Nsight Compute runs a kernel multiple times as @Jackson stated, the effects of uninitialized memory were amplified (I was performing atomicAdd into uninitialized memory).

Answer (score 1):

I followed up on the NVIDIA forums but will post here as well for tracking:

What inconsistencies are you seeing in the output? Nsight Compute runs a kernel multiple times to collect all of its information. So things like print statements in the kernel will show up multiple times. Could it be related to that or is it a value being calculated differently? One other issue is with Unified Memory (UVM) or zero copy memory Nsight Compute is not able to restore those values before each replay. Are you using that in your application? If so, the application replay mode could help. It may be worth trying to see if anything changes.

Comment: I have a matrix of integers that are acting as flags. The values are assigned after checking some conditions of the input signal. After the entire input signal is processed and flags assigned, I copy the matrix to the host and plot the results. When I run the executable nvcc generates, the plot is completely accurate and consistent no matter how many times I run the executable. Yet, when I input the executable into Nsight Compute, since it runs the application while profiling it keeps generating the plot and the plots are inconsistent within runs.

Comment: It's hard to say what's causing that. Would you be able to share a reproducible test case? Have you tried using the application replay mode, which is different than the default kernel replay mode, in Nsight Compute?

Comment: Turns out I was not initializing all the elements of all the shared memory arrays, thus consecutive atomicAdd operations were adding up during the multiple kernel runs you mentioned. Thanks for the help. I'm not sure why cuda-memcheck could not point this out though.